# Lightbox click event doesn't work on chrome and safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

In chrome when I click first time it is working fine.However, in the second time I click the same image. light box doesn't work (chrome).

```
lightBoxpopUp: function () {
    var self = this;
    $('.en-large').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var src = $(this).data('src');
        $('.lightbox-image img').stop().animate({
            opacity: '0'
        }, function () {
            $('.loading').show();
            $(this).attr('src', src);
        }).load(function () {
            $('.loading').hide();
            $(this).stop().animate({
                opacity: '1'
            });
            self.getHeight();
            self.getWidth();
            $('.lightbox-overlay').fadeIn();
            $('#lightbox').fadeIn();
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: please make fiddle for this

Comment: Any error logged in Console?

Comment: No,there is no error in console

Comment: The click event should be called outside of lightBoxpopUp... And then you should call lightBoxpopUp() in the click function. I think :)